# Replacement for COSName.DOCMDP in PDFBox 2.0.4

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm testing the example codes from this page:
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/

But inside the file CreateSignatureBase.java, exactly in the functions `getMDPPermission` and `setMDPPermission`, it calls a property that doesn't exist anymore: `COSName.DOCMDP`. I perused the Pdfbox page and its migration guide and it doesn't mention this property and how to replace it. I also looked into the PDfbox source code (exactly the file COSName.java) and It doesn't have that property, despite this file:
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/cos/COSName.java?view=markup does have it.

I checked both pdfbox-2.0.4.jar and pdfbox-app-2.0.4.jar adding them to the Netbeans project where I'm testing the java files from the pdfbox examples. None of them have the property `COSName.DOCMDP` in the `COSName` class.
Both jars and the pdfbox sourcecode are downloaded from here:
https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x

How can I replace the property `COSName.DOCMDP` in the `CreateSignatureBase` class? Am I getting the right jars?

Comment: It will be in 2.0.5, in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will appear in 2.1.0 version:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3017
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3699

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/cos/COSName.java?annotate=1786065

If you need it for testing purposes, you may download it's SNAPSHOT version from https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/

Or, you may see this example in current stable version - just download 2.0.4 jar and browse examples.

Comment: I didn't see the \examples folder inside the zip file of the pdfbox source code (the CreateSignatureBase doens't have the problematic getMDPPermission and setMDPPermission functions), my mistake was going directly to the examples link in the pdfbox webpage (they're for another pdfbox 2.0 version). Thanks!